# Problema de SDK's na instalação do Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Estou tendo problema na instalção do Android Studio. Eu simplesmente não consigo resolver esse problema de instalar SDK's na pasta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Antes ele tava avisando que havia ascentos no local da minha pasta, e realmente tinha, era o nome de usuário da minha conta no windows 10(usuÁrio), daí mudei e mesmo assim ele não reconhece. Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema do print?

Answer (score 1):

Tive o mesmo problema e resolvi da seguinte forma:

> 1) Apague o seu SDK
>
> 2) Crie um pasta chamada Android na raiz C:
>
> 3) Baixe no site do Android do google o sdk básico ( versão download
>   load instalador )
>
> 4) descompacta na pasta c:/Android
>
> 5) Execute o manager que veio com o adk ( SDK Manager.exe ) 6) Instale
>   todos pacotes necessários para seu projeto
>
> 7) Abra o Android Studio, não inicie nenhum projeto.
>
> 8) Clique em Configure ( na base da janela ) e selecione SSDK Manager
>
> 9) no campo Andorid Sdk Location vc seleciona o pasta sdk q vc baixou
>   Vai ficar assim ( C:\Android\sdk )

Fiz isso e resolveu. espero que lhe ajude tbm

Comment: Obrigado,vou fazer isso. Um dos problemas que tbm estava ocorrendo era no PATCH, dizendo que havia ascentos no caminho do ANDROID SDK. O problema é que o acento estava no nome da minha conta do windows, que tá como "usuário". Eu coloquei outro nome, porém o instalador permanece com "usuário" no patch. Vc sabe como resolver isso? Pq meu medo é fazer isso tudo que vc falou e ele dar erro nisso.

Comment: por que no caminho do sistema ( akele relative patch ) q tem no registro do windows ainda esta com acento. por isso q falei para vc desinstalar tudo e instalar novamente. em outro caminho.

Comment: cara, opinião pessoal, o windows para esse tipo de processamento é mais do que um péssimo so, tenta migrar para o Linux, no começo voce pode ter um pequeno nivel de dificuldades, mas "Larga é a porta que leva para a perdição",ririri

Comment: rsss concordo com vc por isso que aqui em casa eu criei uma VM com o debian 8 e eu so utilizo ele quando vou trabalhar. deixo o ruindows só pra joga d vez em quando